# Почему при обновлении страницы дважды срабатывает $viewContentLoaded?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, angular-ui-router, ui-router

В контроллере есть метод:

```
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
    console.log('$viewContentLoaded');
});
```

При перезагрузке страницы по F5 (cmd + R на маке) в консоле метод засветился дважды.

И при любом переходе метод

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
  console.log('$stateChangeSuccess');
});
```

тоже срабатывает дважды.

Почему так происходит?

Comment: предоставьте [минимальный, полный, воспроизводимый пример.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

[Перевод ответа аналогичного вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000417/angular-js-viewcontentloaded-loading-twice-on-initial-homepage-load)

Это просто особенность реализации директивы uiView. Она запускает событие $viewContentLoaded во время инициализации (функция link). В этот момент состояние еще не известно, но событие уже послано.

Второй раз событие запускается когда $state сервис разрешил все зависимости, подгрузил шаблоны и т.д.

В общем, это случается не из-за плохой конфигурации или из-за того чот шаблоны загрузились дважды. Это просто так работает uiView.

Вы даже можете проверить это, полностью закомментировав ваши определения для state, а также большую часть вашей разметки (за исключением самой директивы ui-view). Все равно $viewContentLoaded сработает один раз.

Немного исходного кода:

uiView определение директивы:

```
{
    restrict: 'ECA',
    terminal: true,
    priority: 400,
    transclude: 'element',
    compile: function (tElement, tAttrs, $transclude) {
      return function (scope, $element, attrs) {
        ...
        updateView(true);
        ...
      }
    }
}
```

функция updateView:

```
function updateView(firstTime) {
  ...
  currentScope.$emit('$viewContentLoaded');
  currentScope.$eval(onloadExp);
}
```

Остальной код можно увидеть на **GitHub** - [viewDirective.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/db68914cd6c821e7dec8155bd33142a3a97f5453/src/viewDirective.js)